# Is there any way to insert some effects I found on codepen without altering my previous work?

Tags: html, css, code-snippets

I want to include some code I found on code pen but when I insert it in my own code, everything gets messed up since the aforementioned effect needs some CSS which clashes with my own. Is there an easy way to insert the code into my own and apply its own CSS only to that part of the code? It's virtually impossible to modify the pen's css because is really big. It would be great to find a way for that code to use only its own CSS while the rest of the page uses the one I wrote.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the link to the pen. And some part of your code that is getting overridden by the pen's CSS. You can try changing the division id or classes but if the pen's CSS is targeting HTML tags then you'll have to add classes to your tags and then apply your custom styles. Please include some code in your question and have a specific question. Refer MCVE guide at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm using a template with, let's say, 5000 lines of code. It's really impossible (at least for me) to check every line in order to find out what tags are being overridden. It would be fine if I could insert the pen's code and apply its css only to it. This is the pen:  https://codepen.io/kacpertn4t/pen/RYzZwG

Comment: The pen you've linked contains SCSS code. Before pasting the whole code from the pen you'll have to first compile the css part and then copy it to your template.

Comment: you can easily change the classes in this pen by using Find & Replace feature available in CodePen. For example, if you press Ctrl+Shift+F in HTML window of CodePen and then replace all {   class="   } with {   class="johann-   } then all the classes with name "more" will get renamed to "johann-more" you can do the same with class names in the css window rename all "more" classes to "johann-more". then compile the css and finally you can copy paste the code to your template. I hope this helps.  Peace   .

Answer (score 0):

Create parent div for the code and give some **class** name to that div of your code. Then to all CSS properties of the code apply that class name as prefix and Bingo !! You're done with overriding error.

```
NOTE : While following above process create class for the code whichever contains less code **(Codepen or your original code)**.
```